# Why does PHP not throw an error when you have a typo in the code when error reporting is set to E_STRICT

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, continue

EDIT: In an effort to make this question not totally useless I'm changing the subject.

**Why does PHP not throw an error when you have a typo like contninue; in the code when error reporting is set to E_STRICT.**

See my below original question. I was trying to continue a foreach loop, but accidentally wrote contninue; instead of continue;, yet I received no warning or error from either NetBeans IDE or PHP when the script was run. I have E_STRICT and E_ALL error reporting on, HTML errors on, display errors on, etc. Is there any way to make programming in PHP more bullet-proof to these kinds of stupid errors? Note that there was no variable or function named contninue. In fact, I can type pretty much anything in a line including dsafdsfdafdsafdsafdsafdsa_FDA9812324398s; and it will not throw an error.

---

Original question: Why doesn't continue in PHP for each loop skip to the next loop?

It's a bit embarassing to post a question like this but here goes...

Here's a little snippet of code from a function. I'm simply trying to recreate an array filtering out one or more items in the array that meet certain criteria, in this case match a postId. (This is development in Wordpress in case you're wondering.)

In my simple foreach loop, the continue; command doesn't appear to be doing its job. At least its not behaving how I would expect from any other language I've used (C, C#, MEL, Javascript, etc.) The echoed output always includes "should have exited but it did not!" even though its after the continue; and should never be executed. Also, the resulting array always contains the filtered content even though "REMOVED " . $postId clearly ran.

```
$posts = get_posts( $args ); // posts is an array of objects
if($posts == null) return; // no posts
if($includeCurrentPost || $postId < 0) return $posts; // we are including all posts, so just return it

// Remove current post id from list since excluding
$newPosts = array();
$count = 0;
foreach($posts as $p) {
    if($p->ID == $postId) {
        echo("REMOVED " . $postId);
        contninue;
        echo("should have exited but it did not!");
    }
    $newPosts[$count++] = $p;
}
return $newPosts;
```

Okay, I normally program in C# and consider myself a decent mid-level programmer. This just doesn't make any sense. @_@ I'm guessing its going to turn out to be some stupid syntax error that PHP is just letting me get away with that I can't see...

PHP version it 5.3 something, Apache, running on Windows Vista.

Comment: Typo: `contninue;` maybe? :) But that would have presented itself with an error, I suppose.

Comment: `continue` just jump to next iteration

Comment: What kind of IDE are u using that doesn't show syntax errors?!

Comment: @Smuuf AGH!! Yes, you are right. I am blind... sigh. I just started on NetBeans. I would have expected something like this to show up as an error but it doesn't, at least out of the box. Embarassing to say the least...

Comment: @Songo : Netbeans... anything better you recommend? I was looking at Eclipse but saw Netbeans was preferred in a couple of comparisons I read.

Comment: I just tested and Netbeans does not show an error for `contninue`. But it does have a lot of useful warnings for unused variables, etc.

Comment: @Guavaman well I use netbeans too and it's great for a free tool. It seems PHP treats `contninue` as a constant. That's why it is important to enable all errors during development.

Comment: I use PSPad - freeware, extendable and lightweight, yay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried your code here:
http://writecodeonline.com/php/

```
$posts = array(1,2,3,4,5);
foreach($posts as $p) {
    if($p == 3) {
        echo("REMOVED " . $p . "\n");
        contninue;
        echo("should have exited but it did not!");
    }
    echo("Other stuff\n");
}
```

It doesn't work because of `contninue` instead of `continue`, but also doesn't have an error by default (this probably means you don't have strict errors on).

When you fix the typo:

```
$posts = array(1,2,3,4,5);
foreach($posts as $p) {
    if($p == 3) {
        echo("REMOVED " . $p . "\n");
        continue;
        echo("should have exited and it did!");
    }
    echo("Other stuff\n");
}
```

It works

Comment: See I told you it would be a typo! ARGH! Thanks for the tip about strict errors. I will set that up. BTW, I'm using NetBeans. Man I miss Visual Studio and C#. :(

Comment: Actually, enabling E_STRICT and E_ALL errors didn't change anything. No errors show in the log file either. I can even type something like FKDSAJ_fewjafojewa; and there will be no error at all.

Comment: Perhaps ask around in the PHP mailing lists or something? Or post a new question with a short code example that sets the error level and then just has a line like `asdf;` and ask why there is no error? I couldn't find anything else in the php docs.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, [continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) ends the current iteration but does not break the loop. [break](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) will end the loop